# Issues with Jenkins Upgrade with huge number of plugins

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, persistent-volumes

I am planning to test upgrade jenkins controller from 2.289 to 2.303 and later in phases.
and i am using shared EBS volume created using a snapshot from the earlier version so that i have a backup of all the existing jobs.

So now during upgrade, using a docker image from the stock jenkins and my necessary plugins that i will be using. I face the following issues:

1. Plugins from the snapshot gets installed in the newer jenkins.
2. I also want to know how i can efficently upgrade the jenkins with the updated plugins in k8s architecture.

Tried different ways but jenkins does not come up due to huge number of plugins, which are unsupported in the newer version of jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

If you are upgrading `Jenkins` I will recommend to switch to approach where you will install plugins before you start `Jenkins`.
This will allow you to track and fix all errors in build phase.
It is describe in [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker#preinstalling-plugins) document and it is just 3 lines of `Dockerfile`

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
COPY --chown=jenkins:jenkins plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN jenkins-plugin-cli -f /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
```

In `plugins.txt` you can put all plugins with pinned versions that you need (eg. `kubernetes:3734.v562b_b_a_627ea_c`)

For the jobs I would say it will be good to switch from current dependence on `EBS` storage and switch to [Job DSL](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl/) where you can configure all your jobs as a code and restore them without any storage.